# what should I set HADOOP_PREFIX to?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I am new with hadoop, and I do not understand everything, I have hadoop 2.5 installed and I would like to run these command in order to start hadoop:

```
$ yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager
$ yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager
$ hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
$ hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
$ mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

when I type this :

```
which hadoop
```

I have this :

```
/usr/bin/hadoop
```

But this is link to :

```
 /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/bin/hadoop
```

what should I set my HADOOP_PREFIX to ? in order to start hadoop
indeed I have this error : yarn-daemon.sh: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your `.bashrc` and it should work:

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin
```

Comment: does not work, I am getting this : "no such file /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh"

Comment: where are the files located?

Comment: I do not know either, under HADOOP_PREFIX, I have only those folders : bin  etc  include  jars  lib  lib64  libexec  meta  share

Comment: I am running this command : $HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager, but I do not see sbin folder, is this normal?